# Dismiss DetailController when UITabBar tab is changed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on an application where I have a `UINavigationController` embedded inside a `UITabBarController`. The `UINavigationController` has a `UITableView` that transitions to a *DetailController* when a cell is tapped.

My question is: I select a cell on **[TAB1]** and transition to the *DetailController*. If I select **[TAB2]** and then go back to **[TAB1]** its still on the detail controller. Is there anyway when **[TAB2]** is selected that I can unwind/dismiss the *DetailController* on **[TAB1]** (i.e. so its showing the table view cells again).

My other line of thinking is that doing this would not leave the UI in the state the user left it in, i.e. after viewing the *DetailController* and pressing **[TAB2]** returning to **[TAB1]** would present the user with the cells in the `UITableView`. It feels better for the application to revert the *DetailController* if you leave the **TAB**, which is why I am asking...

NB: `I present the *DetailController* via a push segue from the`UITableViewCell`.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [UITabBarControlleDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and go back to root view of `UINavigationController` using `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` when tab is changed.

Code example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabBarController.delegate = self;
    return YES;
}

  - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    UIViewController *currentController = tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
         [(UINavigationController *)currentController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: To implement this would you make the UINavigationController the UITabBarControllerDelegate for the UITabBarController. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No, you can set `UIAppDelegate` to be delegate of `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

Comment: Much appreciated Sergey, thank you very much for expanding your answer, now I get it.